# How can I check if a @patched-out python method is called, without changing its behavior?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I've been using the python [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) module for my test-cases. Frequently I decorate my test cases with the `@patch('my_method')` decorator. Then in the body of the test-case, I set the `.return_value` attribute or the `.side_effect` attribute on the patched-out method to simulate its behavior. Also in the test case, I check that the patched-out method was called with `.assert_called_once()`. This works fine. No problems. Example:

```
from mock import patch

@patch('my_method')
def test_case_1(self, mock_my_method):
    mock_my_method.return_value = None
    # Do some testing here
    mock_my_method.assert_called_once()
```

Now I want to do something slightly different: I only want to check that a patched-out method was called once (by using `.assert_called_once()`. ***However***, I don't want to change the method's behavior nor do I want to specify a fake return value. How can I do that?

Comment: That works out of box, you don't need to set return_value or side_effect of a method. If you call a method that calls patched method then mock will increase its call count.

Comment: And if I don't set the `return_value` or the `side_effect` the function will do what it normally does? Really?

Comment: Your title is misleading as your sarcasm obviously says you don't want to patch a method.

Comment: It's not sarcasm. I am sorry it sounded like that. I'm just surprised its so easy.

Comment: It's not. If you don't specify `side_effect` or `return_value`, calling the mock will produce another mock. It won't perform the original function's behavior.

Comment: Ouch, you don't need to apologize, I surely do, sorry.

Comment: @user2357112 "I only want to check that a patched-out method was called once (by using .assert_called_once()." is the relevant part for my comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use `patch` just for its call-logging functionality, without mocking out the original function's behavior, then specify the original function as the `side_effect` of the mock:

```
@patch('my_function', side_effect=my_function)
...
```

The `side_effect` name is misleading. If a mock has a [`side_effect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) function, calling the mock will call the `side_effect` and return or raise whatever the `side_effect` returns or raises. Using the original function as `side_effect` means we get the original function's behavior. (`side_effect` can be a few other kinds of thing besides functions, but we don't need that functionality here.)

Comment: How does this handle the same function imported into multiple modules? I'm guessing it only counts calls in the specific import path you specify in the mock, right? e.g. if I mock out `myfunc` in `mypack.mymod.myfunc` but that function is also used in `mypack.othermod.myfunc`, will it count both calls?

Comment: @medley56: In that regard, it works the same as `patch` always does: patching one reference to a function doesn't affect any other references to that function.